# Как правильно динамически создавать элементы в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть реакт-компонент:

```
import { React } from 'react';

function Component() {
  const arr = ['ad', 'gvsf', 'awd'];
  return (
    <div>
      {}  {/* code here */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

В нем нужно создать блок, содержащий `arr.length` блоков с текстом из `arr` соответственно.

На обычном js я бы написал функцию, создающую контейнер и с помощью `.forEach` перебрал бы массив, создав элементы и поместив их в блок.

Как сделать это на реакт?

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { React } from 'react';

function Component() {
  const arr = ['ad', 'gvsf', 'awd'];
  return (
    <div>
      { arr.map(item => (<span>{item}{' '}</span>)) } 
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

Используй map, возвращай элементы в том виде, в котором надо